# Is it faster to run an SQL count(*) query in a loop, or try to merge it into the parent query?

Tags: mysql, sql, performance, optimization, count

I have an SQL query.

```
SELECT `shifts`.*, `races`.`race_attrition_rate`
FROM `shifts`
JOIN `races` ON `races`.`race_id` = `shifts`.`race_id`
WHERE `shifts`.`race_id` = 'X'
AND `shift_deleted` =0
ORDER BY `shift_name` ASC, `shift_id` ASC
```

That query pulls a list of volunteer shifts from a database. Then I have a PHP loop that, for each shift that was pulled in the above query, runs this SQL query.

```
SELECT COUNT(*) AS `numrows`
FROM `volunteer_shifts`
WHERE `shift_id` = 'Y'
AND `shift_deleted` =0
```

So if there are 5 shifts pulled in the first query, the second query is run 5 times, one time for each shift.

1) Can these two queries be merged together? What would the combined code look like?

2) Is merging these two queries together faster?

3) Merging them together would probably make the code less readable. So what is best practice? Two readable queries or one hard to read but fast query?

Comment: "Faster" without measurement is meaningless.  Is it faster by 10ms?  Or by an hour?  Without measurement, you can't make a real decision.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> 2) Is merging these two queries together faster?

Single query will be definetely faster, as there is no time spent on network activity (just imagine that DB is located at another server, that is quite usual case)

Also separate-queries approach doesn't allow built-in DB query optimizer to do its work

> 1) Can these two queries be merged together? What would the combined code look like?

Following query may work for you:

```
SELECT 
  `shifts`.*,
  `races`.`race_attrition_rate`,
  (SELECT 
      COUNT(*) AS `numrows`
    FROM 
      `volunteer_shifts`
    WHERE
      `volunteer_shifts`.`shift_id` = `shifts`.`shift_id`
    AND 
      `shift_deleted` = 0) AS `volunteer_shifts`
FROM 
  `shifts`
  JOIN `races` ON `races`.`race_id` = `shifts`.`race_id`
WHERE 
  `shifts`.`race_id` = 'X'
AND 
  `shift_deleted` = 0
ORDER BY 
  `shift_name` ASC, `shift_id` ASC
```

> 3) So what is best practice? Two readable queries or one hard to read but fast query?

General rule is "Readability is the main point until you get problems with performance". Just because Computing resources are cheaper than Human resources

Comment: Thank you for answering. This appears to be the simplest way to merge the two queries together. I will probably mark this the best answer later today.

Comment: I have another set of queries that follows this pattern. Do you think it would be better performance wise and code wise to add even more sub-queries to the SELECT statement? If I refactor this other set of queries, I will probably end up with 7 sub-queries in the SELECT statement. All of the queries are of a COUNT(*) or SUM() nature and wouldn't work as inner joins. Thanks in advance for your feedback.

Comment: @AdmiralAdama In most cases I would prefer to use subqueries/grouping

Answer (score 2):

We don't know which one would run faster unless you post your table schema. 
If I were you I would probably run query 1, collect all of the `shift_id`s then run 1 more query that pulls the counts for the list of `shift_id` using `IN`.

Something like this.

```
SELECT COUNT(*) AS `numrows`, `shift_id`
FROM `volunteer_shifts`
WHERE `shift_id` IN ('42','other number', 'more numbers'...)
AND `shift_deleted` =0
GROUP BY `shift_id`
```

Answer (score 1):

In this case, pure SQL would be more maintainable, readable, and efficient than looping at application layer (i.e., PHP). Hence, consider joining the aggregate query as a derived table (notice *shift_id* is now a grouping). Now, the count will appear inline with other fields in one query:

```
SELECT s.*, r.`race_attrition_rate`, agg.`numrows`
FROM `shifts` s
JOIN `races` r ON r.`race_id` = s.`race_id`

JOIN (
      SELECT `shift_id`, COUNT(*) AS `numrows`
      FROM `volunteer_shifts`
      WHERE `shift_deleted` = 0
      GROUP BY `shift_id`
     ) AS agg

ON agg.shift_id = s.shift_id

WHERE r.`race_id` = '17'
AND s.`shift_deleted` = 0
ORDER BY s.`shift_name` ASC, s.`shift_id` ASC
```

Answer (score 0):

If all you want is the count that the second SQL produces, then it would be more readable, and it would be way shorter.

```
SELECT COUNT(*) numrows
FROM shifts
Where shift_id = 42 
   and race_id = '17'
   and shift_deleted = 0
```

Comment: I edited my question to make it clearer. The second query is in a loop of the first query's results. I need a COUNT(*) for each result in the first query.